# VB.net I cannot explicitly state to save an excel workbook within the project directory

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have having issues working out how to save a file without using full length file paths... As I am using the excel namespace the default save directs to documents, rather than the project directory.

Here is what I have been trying :

```
Private Sub createStationsCSV(ByRef station As String)
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'appXL.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Users\****\source\repos\FQR Generator\FQR Generator\bin\Debug\"
    Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
    ' Dim raXL As Excel.Range
    wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Add
    shXL = wbXL.ActiveSheet
    wbXL.SaveAs("FQR Generator Data\Stations\" & station)
    appXL.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: If you deploy the program into users' "Program Files" directories, it won't be able to save there - it's a Windows anti-malware security measure. You could use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FQR Generator Data\Stations\", station)` as the save location instead.

Comment: Why are you passing `station` `ByRef`?

Comment: @Mary It will be changed in the sub once fully done

Comment: @AndrewMorton This was the issue, your help is appreciated :)

Comment: @dkettle01 You're welcome :) In that case, this question is a duplicate of [Where to save application data in .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650209/where-to-save-application-data-in-net-application).

Comment: Recommend you look at using EPPlus rather than excel interop to create your file